# state transitions dosent work from python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, transition

I am trying to containerise existing code which has a state machine to bring up optical device. In the `post_init` state I create a thread which does the rest of the state triggers.

I tried python help slack channel but haven't received any response.

```
 null ----> init ------> connected -----> up -----> down
                   ^ ^             |             ^         | |
                   | |             |             |         | |
                   | +-------------+             +---------+ |
                   |                                         |
                   +-----------------------------------------+
```

```
states = [
    'state_null',
    'state_init',
    'state_connected',
    'state_up',
    'state_down']

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'go_state_init',
     'source': ['state_null', 'state_connected', 'state_down'],
     'dest': 'state_init',
     'before': 'do_state_init',
     'after': 'post_init'},
    {'trigger': 'go_state_connected',
     'source': 'state_init',
     'dest': 'state_connected',
     'before': 'do_state_connected'},
    {'trigger': 'go_state_up',
     'source': ['state_connected', 'state_down'],
     'dest': 'state_up',
     'before': 'do_state_up'},
    {'trigger': 'go_state_down',
     'source': ['state_up'],
     'dest': 'state_down',
     'before': 'do_state_down',
     'after': 'post_down'}]
```

from thread go_state_connected dosent get called.  This works in another code base

```
    # Initialize the OLT state machine
    self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=OpenoltDevice.states,
                           transitions=OpenoltDevice.transitions,
                           send_event=True, initial='state_null')
    self.go_state_init()

def do_state_init(self, event):
    # Initialize gRPC
    self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(self.host_and_port)
    self.channel_ready_future = 
    grpc.channel_ready_future(self.channel)

    self.log.info('openolt-device-created', device_id=self.device_id)

def post_init(self, event):
    self.log.debug('post_init')

    # We have reached init state, starting the indications thread

    # Catch RuntimeError exception
    try:
        # Start indications thread
        self.indications_thread_handle = threading.Thread(
            target=self.indications_thread)
        # Old getter/setter API for daemon; use it directly as a
        # property instead. The Jinkins error will happon on the reason of
        # Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised # during
        # interpreter shutdown)
        self.indications_thread_handle.setDaemon(True)
        self.indications_thread_handle.start()
    except Exception as e:
        self.log.exception('post_init failed', e=e)

def do_state_connected(self, event):
    self.log.debug("do_state_connected")

def indications_thread(self):
    self.log.debug('starting-indications-thread')
    self.log.debug('connecting to olt', device_id=self.device_id)
    self.channel_ready_future.result()  # blocking call
    self.log.info('connected to olt', device_id=self.device_id)
    self.go_state_connected()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue?